# Can pointer operators be overloaded in C++?

Tags: c++

Can the operator `=` be overloaded for class pointers. This example tries to overload 'operator =' for the pointer 'Cutie*':

```
class Cutie    
{
public:
    int Krait;

    Cutie() : Krait(0)
    {
    }
};

Cutie* operator = (Cutie* p, Cutie* q)
{
    if(p == 0)
    {
        if(0 < Krait)
            Krait--;
    }
    else
        Krait++;
}
```

---

the above defintion has errors. I'm looking for a definiton which counts pointer assignments:

```
Cutie c;
Cutie* p = 0;
p = &c;
```

now 'p -> Krait' should be '1'.

Comment: Have you tried compiling it?

Comment: This has errors. This trial is just to clarify the question.

Comment: error: 'Cutie* operator=(Cutie*, Cutie*)' must be a nonstatic member function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't have a non-member overloaded operator function that takes only pointers as its arguments:

> An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or be a non-member function and have at least one parameter whose type is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an enumeration.

Comment: So the pointer operator cannot be overloaded, whether it is defined inside or outside the class?!

Comment: What do you mean by the pointer operator? This is the assignment operator. No, you can't overload the assignment operator for pointers - that would make pointers behave very badly. What are you hoping to be able to do here?

Comment: @CutieKrait Okay, you can't do this. You can however provide types that behave like pointers and do this same job. In fact, `std::shared_ptr` does it.